# Animation Body Rig Mesh is Messed Up

Tags: cycles-render-engine

So I was animating a scene for minecraft. The character rig was completely fine the entire time. Right when I got done animating I even previewed the animation and everything was fine and there was no problems. Then I added more to the animation and the character rig all of a sudden had a glitched mesh. I have no idea what is wrong with it, I believe that I might of accidentally parented it to something. So I tried to get rid of the character meshes parent if that was the case and the entire characters body disappeared. I have no idea what to do. Here is the image of what the glitched mesh looks like. [image]

Comment: Looks like the weight painting got messed up.  Try adding (painting) those parts of the mess to the appropriate bones.

Comment: I tried and it didn't work

Comment: Is there a way to replace the mesh with a new one and reparent the mesh to the already animated bones?